# Using Variant Array containing Range Variables to populate Ranges to be later referenced by range Variable by name is failing

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, variant

Consider the `Subroutine` below.  I almost have what I'm looking for, but it's not quite right.

Knowns to take into account: The `Declarations` statements for this `Module` have setup each variable (Totaling 63 - I've culled the majority to simplify the sample below) as `Public Variables` to be referenced at any time.  I have done similar things with modifying `Boolean` Variable Values, but this is failing for some reason with `Ranges` and I think it has to do with the fact they are `Objects`.

The `For Loop` correctly pulls the relevant data and places it into the relevant `placeholder` within each Variant Array, meaning - the `placeholder` for `StoreStateRng` for example, holds the correct *data* frm the Ranges in the sheet, but when trying to manipulate the actual *`Range Variable` stored **inside** the the placeholder, it fails to be referenced.*

In theory - I would have expected this to physically set the *`Variable "StoreStateRng"`* to the range specified. . .  It does indeed set `rngVars(i)` to the range specified, and gives it a `Variant/Range` `Type` when I inspect it on a `Watch`, but when inspecting the actual `Variable` at the same time, the `Range Variable "StoreStateRng"` is empty!

```vb
'Excerpt of Declarations Statement

'example of 3 of the 63 variables listed in the arrays below
Public Const StoreStateRng_Col As Integer = 23
Public StoreStateRng As Range
Public StoreStateRng_Val As Variant

'the Variant Arrays defined at the beginning of the sub
Public rngVar As Variant
Public rngVars() As Variant
Public rngVarStr() As Variant
Public rngVarCols() As Variant
Public rngVarColStr() As Variant
Public rngVarVals() As Variant
Public rngVarValStr() As Variant


Sub Get_Ranges()
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsNameMain)
  
  rngVars() = Array(StoreStateRng, StoreCityRng, StoreDateRng, StoreNumRng)
  rngVarStr() = Array("StoreStateRng", "StoreCityRng", "StoreDateRng", "StoreNumRng")
  rngVarCols() = Array(StoreStateRng_Col, StoreCityRng_Col, StoreDateRng_Col, StoreNumRng_Col)
  rngVarColStr() = Array("StoreStateRng_Col", "StoreCityRng_Col", "StoreDateRng_Col", "StoreNumRng_Col")

  'Get Known Range that never has blanks in data:
  Set StoreNumRng = ws.Range(Cells(2, StoreNumRng_Col), Cells(2, StoreNumRng_Col))
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0
  'Get Full Range of Known data set to establish beginning and end rows
  rw = StoreNumRng.Row 'Pulled from the removed excerpt above
  EndRw = StoreNumRng.End(xlDown).Row 'Pulled from the removed excerpt above
  
  For i = LBound(rngVars) To UBound(rngVars)
    If VarType(rngVars(i)) = vbObject Then
      Set rngVar = ws.Range(Cells(rw, rngVarCols(i)), Cells(EndRw, rngVarCols(i)))
      Set rngVars(i) = rngVar
      Debug.Print "The Address for " & rngVarStr(i) & " = " & rngVars(i).Address
    End If
  Next i
  Debug.Print StoreStateRng(1, 1).Value 'Fails because I'm assuming this variable is not set.
  
  
End Sub
```

I did try modifying the `.Name` feature of the `Variant's Placeholder` and it references the *`SheetName$COL$ROW`* address properly (and even gives me a `Named Range` to `Goto` in the Sheet), and that `Name.Name` value matches the `Name of the Variable` - but the `Debug.Print StoreStareRng(1,1).Value` fails because the Object itself still is empty.

I feel like I'm really close to figuring it out, but having a hard time wrapping my head around what I'm missing.

The goal is to have named Variables with which to reference throughout the module.  For example - the data set I'm working with is 20+ columns wide, offset roughly 20 columns from another existing set of data, and often between 10-30 rows deep.  What I'm wanting to *avoid* is `fullRange(3,6).Value` for the 3rd row of the *Sheet's* Column 23. . . The *Sheet's* column 23 would be column 6 of the specified range). . . .

Instead, I would like to reference `StoreStateRng(3,1).Value` for this same exact range and use a Constant of the actual sheet's column to modify this should the scope of range change down the line vs trying to touch every single routine which may reference `StoreStateRng` . . .

I'm also hoping to avoid the cumbersome :

```vb
Sub Get_Ranges()
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsNameMain)
  ws.Activate
  Set StoreStateRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreStateRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreStateRng_Col))
  Set StoreCityRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreCityRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreCityRng_Col))
  Set StoreDateRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreDateRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreDateRng_Col))
  Set StoreNumRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreNumRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreNumRng_Col))
  'Repeat until all 21 needed ranges are populated
End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to describe exactly what you see when you run your code - it's quite dense so telling us exactly what error you get and on which line would be useful.  Note when using something like `ws.Range(Cells(2, StoreNumRng_Col),...` the `Cells()` will refer to the ActiveSheet, which may or may not be `ws`.  You sohuld qualify every call to Range() or Cells() with a worksheet reference.

Comment: When you do this `Set rngVars(i) = rngVar` you're *replacing* the original Range variable with a different one, not assigning the original one to `rngVar`

Comment: @TimWilliams, the `ws.Range` statement is qualified as a Worksheet - `ws` is also a `Public` variable, which is then instantiated when I use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsNameMain)` (which - as you may guess - is also a public variable).

Comment: It's not about what `ws` references - the calls to `Cells()` inside that `ws.Range()` won't reference `ws` unless that happens to be the activesheet (or unless the code is inside the worksheet code module for `ws`)

Comment: Ah - yes - I've seen this behavior.  Normally I call a ws.activate to ensure it's on this sheet.  The failure isn't there - it's in the fact that the Variable I'm hoping to store inside of `rngVars(i)` isn't being set as you've described in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
Set rngVars(i) = rngVar
```

you're replacing the original Range variable with a different one, not assigning the original one to `rngVar`

Simpler version:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, arrRanges As Variant
    
    arrRanges = Array(rngA, rngB)
    
    Set arrRanges(0) = Range("A1:A5")  'This *replaces* rngA...
    
    Debug.Print rngA.Address           'Error - rngA is still Nothing
    
End Sub
```

EDIT - your "cumbersome" example could be streamlined to be quite maintainable...

```vb
Sub SetRanges()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNameMain)
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(rw, "A"), ws.Cells(endRw, "A")).EntireRow
        Set StoreStateRng = .Columns(StoreStateRng_Col)
        Set StoreCityRng = .Columns(StoreCityRng_Col)
        Set StoreDateRng = .Columns(StoreDateRng_Col)
        Set StoreNumRng = .Columns(StoreNumRng_Col)
        '...
        '...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok - this helps me understand what the problem is, but not how to solve it.  So the next thing to figure out is - how do I _**modify**_ the Range Variable stored in `rngVars(i)` ?

Comment: You just use the range stored in `rngVars(i)` - if you have an array of ranges then you don't need to reference the ranges outside of the array.

Comment: I don't want to do this by numbers - with all the ranges being stored (21) - that's a lot of ways to make mistakes (which is what I'm trying to resolve).

Is there a method in which to utilize a for loop with a list of strings instead, and reference this?  I think I may have touched on it a little bit when playing with the `.Name` attribute, as it produced a named range on the sheet - might look at this as the route, but would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Looks like you're matching an array of "names" with an array of "items" in which case maybe consider using a dictionary instead eg `Set dict(rngVarStr(i)) = rngVar`

Comment: Ahhh - I thought about using a dictionary.  So - effectively - `rngVarStr(i)` - the _name string_, would be the `key`, with `rngVar` as the _value_.  This isn't as 'clean' as using the `Range` variables, because later I would still have to iterate through the list of `Range` variables and assign them the values in order to utilize the `StoreStateRng(Row,Column)` construct. . . correct?

Comment: I can't really tell what your use case is here, so I can't really offer much help for a general "best" solution.  When I see that many variables I can't help but wonder if all that metadata would be better stored on a hidden worksheet and referenced from there.  Or at least use constants so you basically have "named values" you can use directly in your code.

Comment: The goal is to take the long list of Range Variables stored in the `rngVars` array and populate that list of Variables with their specific data (sometimes 30 rows at a chunk) so I can reference only what I need with that range without having to figure out which row/column I need.  I'll add my use case in the question to help clarify.

Comment: Thanks for posting your edit.  I've employed this methodology before, but had been really hopeful that I'd be able to assign the required ranges to these variables using a for loop...

Perhaps combining the Array with a separate function to assign the variables via their array. . .?  Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: If it were my project I'd figure that prepping all those variables and arrays in order to use the loop is as much if not maybe more work than the "cumbersome" approach, and has the downside of being more complex to review/maintain than the "simple but boring" method.

Comment: The wisdom in your last statement . . . this took me a mere 5 minutes. . . at best. . . to complete. . . I've wasted hours researching my problem. . .  A lesson of "Simplicity over Coolness" that needs to be hammered into my brain.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally implemented the method provided by Tim, and got a horrible `1004 - Application-error or Object-error` when attempting to use this and access the ranges afterward.  I'm ultimately keeping Tim's answer as the marked answer because he was ***right on merit*** even if his method caused me an unforseen error later on.  Would love some insight on the nature of the phenomenon I show below (`Object not defined` error). . .

Using the following snippet:

```
Sub SetRanges()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNameMain)
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(rw, "A"), ws.Cells(endRw, "A")).EntireRow
        Set StoreStateRng = .Columns(StoreStateRng_Col)
        Set StoreCityRng = .Columns(StoreCityRng_Col)
        Set StoreDateRng = .Columns(StoreDateRng_Col)
        Set StoreNumRng = .Columns(StoreNumRng_Col)
        '...
        '...
    End With
    Debug.Print StoreNumRng(1, 1).Value 'Error 1004
End Sub
```

If I try to reference the value of a range using the `rangeVar(row, col).value` method, I received the `1004` error even though the Range Variables themselves are fully populated - I cannot understand the reason why it fails, so ultimately I did have to resort to using:

```
Sub Set_Ranges()
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsNameMain)
  ws.Activate
  Set StoreStateRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreStateRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreStateRng_Col))
  Set StoreCityRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreCityRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreCityRng_Col))
  Set StoreDateRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreDateRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreDateRng_Col))
  Set StoreNumRng = ws.Range(Cells(rw, StoreNumRng_Col),Cells(endRw, StoreNumRng_Col))
  'Repeat until all 21 needed ranges are populated
  Debug.Print StoreNumRng(1, 1).Value 'No Error and expected value prints.
End Sub
```

I believe a large portion of this is that for some reason, *even though the Ranges are fully qualified as far as I can tell* - when the error occurs and I debug, I get an `Object not defined` error here:

```
'Code code code
    Set StoreStateRng = .Columns 'Insert Error on `.Columns`(StoreStateRng_Col)
                                 'Note - All _Col values are correctly set.
```

[image: .Columns Error. . .]